# Should I use Linux's acct (BSD process accounting) to track a process behavior?

Tags: linux, process, trace

I have a daemon process (`slapd`) which sometimes stops with no apparent reason. No segfault occurs. Nothing special in the logs.

So, I'm trying to use `acct` to track the process' life, especially its exit value. The `man` says that the kernel does log this value. Surprisingly, my `dump-acct` does not show this information...

I had to change the source by adding this line in the `print_pacct_record()` function:

```
(void)fprintf(out, "%4u|", rec->ac_exitcode >> 8);
```

<sup>EDIT: this change has been [recently added mainstream](http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/trunk/pacct_rd.c?root=acct&r1=89&r2=88&pathrev=89).</sup>

However, I feel this won't be enough to discover what the problem is.

**Is there better ways to track how the program exits?** A stack trace, for example, would be interesting. The "last seconds trace" would be even better.

I thought of `strace` or `ltrace` but the program can run for days before it "stops itself". I fear "tracing" will impact performance. I don't know if `gdb` could help.

Comment: You could attach to it with gdb, give gdb the `break exit` and `break _exit` commands, continue the program, and wait. You ought to be able to get a stack trace of the functions that called exit. Or if it dies because of a signal. Of course, if it exits because `main` returns, it won't be that interesting.

Answer (score 1):

What about if you use `strace` and redirect the output of it to a file using the `-o` option?

`[root@host ~]# strace -o /root/slapd_strace.log slapd --parameters --you --want`

Answer (score 0):

Try running `strace` under either `screen` or `tmux`. Once it's running you can disconnect, and only reconnect when required. `screen` keeps a scroll buffer (as might `tmux`) so you don't even need to worry about important clues scrolling off the top of the page.

```
screen -h 1000
strace ...
# disconnect with Ctrl-a d
```

Later

```
screen -r
```

Comment: You'll probably want to increase the size of the scroll-back buffer, as the default is 100 lines. Use the `-h NUM` arg to set it at start. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Invoking-Screen) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Scrollback.html#Scrollback)

Comment: Or use `strace -fp PID 2>&1 | tail -n 200 > strace.log`, but I wonder "stracing" has a significant impact on performance.

Comment: @Totor I think that If I were going to use `screen` at all I would prefer `strace -fp PID 2>&1 | tee strace.log` so that I could see in real-ish time what was going on

Comment: @SteveWills thank you for that suggestion. Now added to the Answer